# Tracking Google Slide events with Hubspot

Tags: google-apps-script, hubspot, google-slides-api, google-slides, hubspot-crm

We use Google Slides to share decks with customers and we also use Hubspot as a CRM. We would like to send our decks directly from Hubspot and track the events inside the deck back to the user. (ie. which slides did they look at, what links did they click on, etc.)

If you import a Google Slide Deck into Hubspot, you can track which slides they view, however you cannot track the links within the slides. Just as importantly, the import process simply turns the decks into PDF documents so all your gifs/vids are lost, there are some artifacts that occur from the transposition (ie. graphic design errors) and the ability to update the deck and see those updates posted in the viewable version.

If you simply publish the deck on Google, you get all the interactivity, but there is no way to insert Hubspot's tracking code to track activity like you would be able to on your website.

The best solution we have come up with is to import to Hubspot and lose the fidelity/risk the artifacting and then host all the destination links to our case videos on our website where we do have the Hubspot code implemented.

Obviously, this is not ideal and I would prefer to have a solution where we can retain the fidelity and visual precision of our content as well as track all events within the decks.

Is anyone doing something similar or have a solution implemented using Hubspot and Google Slides? I would appreciate any thoughts or feedback as well.

Thanks.